# Text hyperlink linking to another page while passing id with thymeleaf and spring data

Tags: html, spring, thymeleaf

I'm trying to display the e.name text as hyperlink that links to /events/details in the same way as this follow button does:

```
<form th:action="@{/events/details}" method='POST'>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type='submit' name='details' th:value='${e.id}'>View</button>
        </form>
```

I've tried doing it the two following ways:

```
<td><a th:href="@{/events/details}" th:value='${e.id}' th:text="${e.name}">My Event</a></td>
```

As well as:

```
          <td><a th:action="@{/events/details}" method='POST' th:value='${e.id}' th:text="${e.name}">My Event</a></td>
```

However, neither of these work (as well as some other variations I tried).

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Read up on the [standard URL syntax](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html) for information on forming URLs.  In your case, this should work:

```
<td><a th:href="@{/events/details(details=${e.id})}" th:text="${e.name}">My Event</a></td>
```

Comment: unfortunately I had tried this before but also didn't work.


When pressing the "view" button, the URL at the top only shows http://localhost:8080/events/details (although the id is still passed). When making the hyperlink work like this, the URL at the top shows http://localhost:8080/events/details?details=3 so it clearly works differently

Comment: Thu Mar 21 11:52:11 UTC 2019
There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405).
Request method 'GET' not supported

Comment: Oh, you need a POST.  That's just not possible with a link.  You need to either: 1. use the form you've created, but style the button to look like a link -- bootstrap has this concept: `<button type="button" class="btn btn-link">Link</button>` or 2. use javascript to submit a form, when you click the link.

Comment: sweet cheers, was using a button as a placeholder already but thought there must have been a way of doing it as a link, at least now I know :)